# Discord Python cog_check issue

Tags: python, discord, permissions, discord.py, bots

New to coding. I want to prevent my bot from responding to itself/other bots, and I'm trying to invoke a cog_check but can't make it work properly. Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
class CommandsMisc(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    async def cog_check(self, ctx):
        if ctx.author.bot:   # also tried: if ctx.author == self.client.user:
            await exit()

    @commands.Cog.listener("on_message")   # example cog command
    async def print(self, message):
        if '!guide' in message.content:
            await message.reply(Guide_Text)
        else:
            pass
```

Since some people seem to lack reading comprehension skills, my question is how can I best utilize "cog_check" in Discord.py so that all subsequent commands/listeners in the cog will check whether the message.author is the bot and then won't execute if it is?

Comment: ['Can somebody help me?' is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/11107541). Can you please ask an actual question? You can see [ask] for guidance. As long as you follow the guidance in ["What is the proper way to approach Stack Overflow as someone totally new to programming?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254572/11107541), then [you don't need to tell us that you are new to `X`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296391/11107541).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you want is a custom command decorator. You can do this as follows:

```
def is_not_bot():
    async def predicate(ctx):
        return not ctx.author.bot
    return commands.check(predicate)
```

You place this in your cog class, then on any command inside the cog you can use the decorator `@is_not_bot()`

What does this do, exactly? Well, we create a function which can be used as a command decorator (`@is_not_bot()`). Inside this, we create a function called `predicate`. This predicate will return `True` if the user is **not** a bot. We then call `return commands.check(predicate)` inside the parent function. This will allow us to use this as a decorator.

[discord.py docs reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.check)

Answer (score 0):

what you can have is a `on_message` event, which can do checks on the message before processing the command, something like this

```py
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.all())

# or if you made your subclass of Bot or its variants

class CustomBot(commands.Bot):

    def __init__(self):
        ...

bot = CustomBot()

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return # this is a bot, so we can early exit

    # any other checks

    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: I tried this in the cog, but it didn't work.

@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author.bot:
            return
        if message.author == self.client.user:
            return
        await self.client.process_commands(message)

Comment: @1FattyGoldfish not ``commands.Cog.listener()`` but ``bot.event``. Where you are constructing a covariant of ``Bot``, have that instance decorate the ``on_message`` async function I have defined. It would force any command to first check the message before getting processed.

Comment: I tried this in the main file with bot.event, but it doesn't seem to read for some reason. In my main, I have my cogs loaded, asyncio.run(main()) (instead of bot.run()) as per the new discord updates, and client.event for on_ready and for on_message, but neither events execute.

Answer (score 0):

`exit()` will just make your entire program close. `cog_check` should return a **Boolean** that indicates if the command should run or not. In your case, you don't return anything if it's okay, so it returns `None` which is falsey, so your check always fails.

Make it return True if it should succeed, and False if it should fail.

#### Edit

The `ext.commands` framework **already prevents bots from running your commands**, so this is not something you should even have to worry about.

The reason your `cog_check` still doesn't do anything is because you **don't have any commands**. You're using an `on_message` listener to manually parse messages, instead of creating commands. Your "example cog command" **is not a command, it's just an event listener**. Those are two very different concepts.

`cog_check` is only invoked when actual *commands* are run, not before dispatching events like `on_message`, so this doesn't have any effect here. If you parse commands in `on_message`, checks aren't used at all.

See the docs for `ext.commands` for how to create commands: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/index.html

Comment: I tried "return False" (as well as "pass" and "break", the latter which didn't register in my code for some reason), but no change.

Comment: I've updated my answer, you're not implementing commands correctly (or at all) so `cog_check` doesn't do anything.

Comment: Ah, okay. I have a few commands, but most of my "commands" need to be read in the middle of text (e.g. "!guide" versus "check this !guide"), which is why I made them listeners instead. In that case I'd have to go back and manually code the exception into every listener/event?

Comment: In that case yes. Checks, cogs, commands, or anything else related to the `Bot` framework will not be of use to you.